# Reading block from MTD flash with ioremap

Tags: c, linux-kernel, ioremap

I would like to know the expected result of reading block data from MTD flash, as per the code below:

```c
#define PHY_ADDR 0x80000000   // certain physical memory location
void *dst;
dst = ioremap(PHY_ADDR,len);  // ioremapping
mtd_image->_read(mtd, from, len, retlen, dst);  // reading from MTD flash to dst buffer with len length
```

So will this code write the read data to the physical memory address `0x80000000`? or will just put the data in the pointer dst? Where I can find the read data in the physical memory (using gdb x/16x `memory address` for example)?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is unclear, please see help center and edit your question by giving some context.

Comment: How did MTD FLASH get mapped to the physical address `0x80000000` ?

Answer (score 0):

With `ioremap` you map physical memory to the pointer `dst`. This means that `mtd_read` reads the address range `from` to `from + len` on device `mtd` and writes it to physical address `0x80000000` through pointer `dst`.